# Grafana and Prometheus: add metrics automatically

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm using Grafana and Prometheus to monitor our server. We have a lot of database procedures like "select_users" or "insert_task". In order to monitor how many pending database procedure calls are there in the server, we add data points for every procedure call in Prometheus dynamically. Now we have data points like "pending_select_users", "pending_insert_task" in Prometheus.

However, since there are so many database procedures(and the number will increase during developing), it's not very practical for us to add metrics in Grafana for each data point manually. Is there a way we can add metrics dynamically in Grafana? Since all the data point have a common name prefix("pending_"), can we add metrics in Grafana with wildcard? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Grafana uses JSON as the underlying dashboard DSL, you could dynamically create dashboards, every time you add a new metric, and import it (via API) into Grafana.
I'd add an automation on top of your Prometheus targets, scrape the metrics, and if new metrics (with the required prefix) are found without a matching dashboard, the automation would create it and import it into Grafana.
Grafana API: http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/ (specifically for [Dashbboards](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/)).

Answer (score 1):

The solution described by @Eitan is definitely feasible. The same goes for using a library like [grafonnet](https://github.com/grafana/grafonnet-lib) to generate dashboards dynamically.

But the simplest approach in my opinion would be to create a variable in Grafana that contains all the label values you are interested in. Something like

`label_values(metric_name{label_name=~"prefix*"}, label_name)`

should work for that. And then use the repeating panels / rows feature of Grafana to repeat a set of panels for every value in the variable. Though this could get out of hand if you have dozens / hundreds of distinct values.

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/repeat-panels-or-rows/
- https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/09/learn-grafana-how-to-automatically-repeat-rows-and-panels-in-dynamic-dashboards/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate just a single dashboard from your Proimetheus metrics sample, you can use this service:

http://eljah.tatar/micrometer2grafana/